# Wrong Routing for motorbikes in graphhopper WEB gui

Tags: routes, openstreetmap, graphhopper

I tried out the graphhopper routing engine and with the

[following example](https://graphhopper.com/maps/?point=50.80447%2C7.183256&point=50.813013%2C7.218876&locale=de-DE&vehicle=motorcycle&weighting=fastest&elevation=true&layer=Omniscale)

there seem to be some routing flaws. From my understanding the turn restrictions of the OSM data are not properly followed or the OSM data model needs to be improved.

Does somebody have a clue where the problem is?

Ufux

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a bug tracker for GraphHopper or OSM. Re-ask your question at http://help.openstreetmap.org/ or https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues.

Comment: It is a combination of two issues, e.g. if you attach ch.disable=true at least the second problem is solved as there is some data in OSM for turn restrictions https://graphhopper.com/maps/?point=50.80447%2C7.183256&point=50.813013%2C7.218876&locale=de-DE&vehicle=motorcycle&weighting=fastest&elevation=true&layer=Omniscale&ch.disable=true But even without turn restriction data this should not happen and is related to speed estimation, see our issues pointed out from @scai